# find previous method to find url before specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, siblings

I would like to find the previous  tag before the class= 'field-news-pillars'
the html looks like this:

```
<span class="field-content"><a href="/news/building-business">Building a Business</a></span>
<div> <div>
<span class="date-display-single">Jun 29, 2020</span></div> </div>
<div> <div>
<div class="field-news-pillars">
    Entrepreneurial Spirit  </div>
</div> </div>
```

I want to get the href link above the class="field-news-pillars" == 'Entrepreneurial Spirit'

I know that there are easier ways to find the href links from the html but I am trying to filter all of the links, and I would only like to select links that are the previous  tag to the class="field-news-pillars". This is what I have tried.

```
last_link = soup.find(class_='field-news-pillars', text ='Entrepreneurial Spirit' )
print(last_link.find_previous('a')['href'])

error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_previous'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` needs a tag name.

```
In [174]: html = """<span class="field-content"><a href="/news/building-business">Building a Business</a></span>
     ...: <div> <div>
     ...: <span class="date-display-single">Jun 29, 2020</span></div> </div>
     ...: <div> <div>
     ...: <div class="field-news-pillars">
     ...:     Entrepreneurial Spirit  </div>
     ...: </div> </div>"""

In [175]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [176]: last_link = soup.find("div", class_='field-news-pillars')

In [177]: print(last_link.find_previous('a')['href'])
/news/building-business
```

If you want to filter by text,

```
n [189]: import re

In [190]: last_link = soup.find("div", class_='field-news-pillars', text=re.compile('Entrepreneurial Spirit*'))

In [191]: print(last_link.find_previous('a')['href'])
/news/building-business
```

Comment: Thank you @bigbounty, I am wondering I need to filter all the entries with class_='field-news-pillars', and I was trying to do that with (class_='field-news-pillars', text ='Entrepreneurial Spirit' ), because in the full html not all the text attributes = 'Entrepreneurial Spirit', is there a way I can leave this in the code to filter some of the items?

Comment: @AndrewLittle1 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the value using css selector if you have BS4 4.7.1 or above without using regex.

```
html='''<span class="field-content"><a href="/news/building-business">Building a Business</a></span>
<div> <div>
<span class="date-display-single">Jun 29, 2020</span></div> </div>
<div> <div>
<div class="field-news-pillars">
    Entrepreneurial Spirit  </div>
</div> </div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

item1=soup.select_one('.field-news-pillars:contains("Entrepreneurial Spirit")')
print(item1.find_previous('a')['href'])
```